# Cypher: play inheritance rules

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have nodes organized in tree ( (:Object)-[:PARENT]->(:Object) )
An Object can use many Item  ( {:Object)-[:USE]->(:Item) )

We would like play an inheritance rule:
if the parent uses one item and the son do not have an item with the same properties => the son will use parent's item.

The following code works fine, but become very slow on large sets (we have about 4k Objects, an Object may have 2k USE)

```
MATCH (p:Object)
WHERE p.rank = 1
WITH p
MATCH (p)-[:PARENT]->()-[:USE]->(used)
WHERE NOT exists((p)-[:USE]->(:Item {
                        property1:used.property1,
                        property2:used.property2,
                        property3:used.property3}))
MERGE (p)-[:USE]->(used);
```

Have you a better solution ?

-- UPDATE --

After study, it seems the slowness is due to the size of the transaction (we are adding several millions of relationship).
So we are now seeking a way to split the transaction, to obtain something like this:

```
DO {
    MATCH (p:Object)
    WHERE p.rank = 1 AND p.updated IS null
    WITH p LIMIT 50
    MATCH (p)-[:PARENT]->()-[:USE]->(item)
    WHERE NOT exists((p)-[:USE]->(:Item {
                        property1:item.property1,
                        property2:item.property2,
                        property3:item.property3}))
    MERGE (p)-[:USE]->(item)
    SET p.updated=true

    COMMIT
} WHILE(something updated)
```

Currently the only way we found is to do external scripts (powershell or python).
Is it possible to do this in Cypher ?

Comment: Do you really want to make redundant copies of `Item` nodes? You could instead just query for "inherited" `Item` nodes as necessary,

Comment: A son item may override parent's one. for example:  
`(parent)-[:USE]->(:Item {name:A, value1})`  
`(parent)-[:USE]->(:Item {name:B, value1})`  
and 
`(son)-[:USE]->(:Item {name:A, value2})`  
I would like to add:  
`(son)-[:USE]->(:Item {name:B, value1})`  from parent

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

Instead of millions of additional relationships, you could instead query for inherited Item properties when necessary.

For instance, to start a query for `Object` 123 (that needs to take the  inherited properties into account):

```
MATCH (p:Object)
WHERE p.id = 123
MATCH path=(p)-[:PARENT*0..]->()-[:USE]->(used)
WITH p, used
ORDER BY LENGTH(path) DESC
WITH p, REDUCE(t = x, x IN COLLECT(used) | apoc.map.merge(t, PROPERTIES(v))) AS used
...
```

By the way, you would need some of the same logic anyway even if you had the extra relationships you originally asked for.

Note: This algorithm (which sorts by descending `path` length) only works properly if there is a single leaf ancester and a single path to that ancester.

Comment: 1/ In my code, there is no node replication, just relationship added between son and parent's item. Functionally, it is what we expect: "The son inherit an item from parent if the item is not overridden by the son". 2/ your query is interesting, but do not handle the whole tree (parent of parent of ...) and we would like to keep queries as simple as possible (much more people doing queries than people feeding the graph)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In our case, we would prefer to play this inheritance business rule on graph feeding time. Doing this, we will simplify queries and reduce the risk of errors on business rules appliance (but, indeed, graph grows a lot).